# delay in displaying QStackedWidget Item in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qt-events

I am using QStackedWidget item. But for the first time it is taking time and after a while it is working properly.

```
mymainwindow::mymainwindow() : QMainWindow()
{

    stack = new QStackedWidget();
    list = new QListWidget();
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Hello U have clicked the first menu"));
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Second ListWidget Item"));
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Last Widget Item"));

    widget = new QWidget();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Main Window");

    list->addItem("New Item 1");
    list->addItem("New Item 2");
    list->addItem("New Item 3");
    list->setFixedSize(200,100);

    QVBoxLayout *vertical = new QVBoxLayout();
    vertical->addWidget(label);
    vertical->addWidget(list);
    vertical->addWidget(stack);
    stack->hide();

    widget->setLayout(vertical);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
}

void mymainwindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{

    switch (event->key()) {

    case Qt::Key_Down:
        connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Enter:
        stack->show();
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Escape:
        stack->hide();
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: "it is taking time and after a while it is working properly." -> what do you mean? What needs to work properly with a delay in your opinion?

Comment: I mean StackedWidget items are not changing as per the listwidget item for short time say 30 sec. Then after 30 sec it is working properly and all stackedwidget items are displaying.

Comment: "StackedWidget items are not changing" -> what changes exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean when i am pressing key up or key down button for changing the Listwidget Item, StackedWidget item should change as per their currentIndex.

Comment: "connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));" -> that logic seems to be fuzzy to me. Also, your connection will not take any effect for the first down/up instantly if there are other events ongoing because that is where you set the connection up. Have you tried the connection in the constructor instead? You could also try Qt::DirectConnection for the fifth parameter.

Comment: I have to write it under KeyPressEvent. That is why i m writing it under KeyPressEvent function. I tried using Qt::DirectConnection but then also it is taking time

Comment: Why do you need to do in the press event?

Comment: I have to continue it in press event coz I have to change the StackWidget Item by clicking Keyboard button like KeyUp

Comment: You should put your connect statements somewhere else (e.g. in your constructor) like Laszlo stated. There is no point in establishing the same connection every time you press the up or down key. `Every connection you make emits a signal, so duplicate connections emit two signals.`

Comment: @thuga: that is not correct. The second connection will just give false. It will not make the connection duplicated.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes it will. It says so in the docs, and I just tested it.

Comment: @thuga, yes, apologies, you are right, I meant Qt::UniqueConnection. IMO, that should be the default behavior as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well :

- You are overriding `QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` and completely disregarding the default implementation.
- Qobject::connect at each key press is a mistake. You seem to have your own interpretation of what it does. ***read the docs***
- You **must not** listen to key press of the main window to know items of the listwidget are changing.
- The proper way of shortcuts is to add a Qaction, and then associate a shortcut to this action. Why? If the widgets inside `stack` need to receive "Enter" key events (like a `QButton`), your UI will be completely bogus because you are manipulating the visibility at the same time.

Basically what you want is to move connection to the constructor of your window, and to 
make sure the key events are always processed

```
mymainwindow::mymainwindow() : QMainWindow()
{

    stack = new QStackedWidget();
    list = new QListWidget();
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Hello U have clicked the first menu"));
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Second ListWidget Item"));
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Last Widget Item"));

    widget = new QWidget();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Main Window");

    list->addItem("New Item 1");
    list->addItem("New Item 2");
    list->addItem("New Item 3");
    list->setFixedSize(200,100);

    QVBoxLayout *vertical = new QVBoxLayout();
    vertical->addWidget(label);
    vertical->addWidget(list);
    vertical->addWidget(stack);
    stack->hide();

    connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    list->setCurrentRow(2);//last, to test 

    widget->setLayout(vertical);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
}


void mymainwindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{

    switch (event->key()) {

    case Qt::Key_Enter:
        stack->show();
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Escape:
        stack->hide();
        break;
    }
    QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Still, this is a nightmare.

**Edit:**
If the focus is on the list widget, changing rows in the list with the keyboard will trigger the signal.

Comment: BUt how to interact with the key_Up and Key_Down event

Answer (score 1):

I would personally suggest to move the connections from your event to the constructor as per my comments earlier since that would be a cleaner design, although we do not quite get what you are trying to achieve. Hence, as per your request, I am providing some code below, which I *guess*, you could do:

```
...
case Qt::Key_Down:
    connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    break;
case Qt::Key_Up:
    connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
    break;
...
```

to:

#### mymainwindow.h

```
mymainwindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
    QTimer m_timer;
    bool m_ready;
};
```

#### mymainwindow.cpp

```
mymainwindow::mymainwindow()
    : QMainWindow()
    , m_ready(false)
{

    stack = new QStackedWidget();
    list = new QListWidget();
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Hello U have clicked the first menu"));
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Second ListWidget Item"));
    stack->addWidget(new QLineEdit("Last Widget Item"));

    widget = new QWidget();
    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Main Window");

    list->addItem("New Item 1");
    list->addItem("New Item 2");
    list->addItem("New Item 3");
    list->setFixedSize(200,100);

    QVBoxLayout *vertical = new QVBoxLayout();
    vertical->addWidget(label);
    vertical->addWidget(list);
    vertical->addWidget(stack);
    stack->hide();

    widget->setLayout(vertical);
    setCentralWidget(widget);

    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(delayEvent()));
    m_timer.setSingleShot(true);
    m_timer.start(5000);
}

void mymainwindow::delayEvent()
{
    m_ready = true;
}


void mymainwindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{

    switch (event->key()) {

    case Qt::Key_Down:
        if (m_ready)
             connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        if (m_ready)
            connect(list,SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(int)),stack,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Enter:
        stack->show();
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Escape:
        stack->hide();
        break;

    }
}
```

Then, use this variable for the events to see if you are "ready" or not. Also, you would need to use Qt::UniqueConnection for the fifth parameter when connecting to avoid duplicated connections, or just use the m_ready guard or any other for that purpose.

But really, this sounds like a fishy design.

Comment: I am agree with your code sir. But i am just asking how to interact via Key_up and Key_down press event

Comment: @user3153003: as I wrote in my reply, use m_ready in the event handler to make the distinction whether you connect properly or not.

Comment: @user3153003: that is not a class, but a boolean variable...

Comment: When i used your code, Segmentation fault is coming

Comment: @user3153003 you did something inappropriate then. It is really hard to tell without a trace, but either way, this code should be working. It is possible your other code is causing the crash.

Comment: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)
candidate expects 5 arguments, 3 provided.
These error is coming coz v r providing only 3 arguments for timer connect function

Comment: @user3153003: you are doing it wrong. This works for me, and I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: When i wrote &timer then it is throwing above error and if i am not passing its address i.e, directly passing timer in            connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),SLOT(delayEvent()));             then segmentation fault is coming.